# name 'headers' is not defined

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Недавно я начал изучать питон и столкнулся с данной проблемой

Нижу я прикрепил код, проблема может быть видна, но я не знаю где

Заранее спасибо!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

url = 'https://magnit.ru/promo/'


def collect_data(city_code='2398'):
    cur_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M')
    FakeUserAgent = UserAgent()

    headers = {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
        'User-Agent': ua.random
    }

    cookies = {
        'mg_geo_id': f'{city_code}'
    }


responce = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)

with open(f'index.html', 'w') as file:
    file.write(responce.text)


def main():
    collect_data(city_code='2398')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

url = 'https://magnit.ru/promo/'

def collect_data(city_code='2398'):
    cur_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M')
    ua = UserAgent()

    headers = {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
        'User-Agent': ua.random
    }

    cookies = {
        'mg_geo_id': f'{city_code}'
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies)

    with open(f'index.html', 'w') as file:
        file.write(response.text)


def main():
    collect_data(city_code='2398')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Нужно переместить блок кода, в котором определена переменная headers, внутрь функции collect_data()

Comment: Точно, я этого не заметил. Спасибо!

Comment: если помог, отметьте галочкой

Comment: У меня еще проблема появилась, после того как приходит html файл в нем сбита кодировка. Что делать?

Comment: :) оформить вопрос в котором описать возникшую проблему и прочее :)

Comment: хорошо. я понял